# Calling a method from another component to keep data in sync

Tags: html, angular, components, web-deployment, two-way-binding

**Problem**

I can not refresh a variable, and thus select dropdown in the `club-list-component` after I create a club in the `create-club-component`

**Context:**

I am developing an application which randomly select a person from a team, from a club. First I made 1 component which concluded all the functionality, but as that would be ugly I wanted to seperate the different components and functions.

**What I tried:**

I've tested the functionality and the dropdown-box refreshes after creating a club, if all code is contained in 1 component.

**Code snippets**

I have the following pieces of code to share (some left away for readability):

**create-club.component.ts:**

```
 @Input() clubDetails = {name: ''};

createClub() {
    this._clubService.createClub(this.clubDetails).subscribe((data: {}) => {
    });
    alert('Club Created');
  }
```

**club-list.component.ts:**

```
  public clubs = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshClublist();
  }

  refreshClublist() {
    this._clubService.getClubs().subscribe(data => this.clubs = data);
  }
}
```

**club-list.component.html**

```html
<div>
  <div class="alert alert-primary">
    Select a club from the list
  </div>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let club of clubs" [value]="club.id">
      {{club.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**What do I try to archieve:**
Once i create my club from the popup modal in `create-club.component.html`, I want to have the dropdown box in `club-list.component.html` to be refreshed

In my mind best case scenario would be:

1. [club-list-component] ngOnInit(refreshClublist()) {}
2. [create-club.component]createClub()
3. [club-list-component] refreshClublist() (called after createClub() in step 2)

Comment: there are several approaches to handle communication between components and each of them has it is own use case. in your situation i would suggest is to call `refreshClublist()` just after your popup modal is closed. in order to achieve this there must be some kind of close event fired after the modal is closed. for example there is an `afterClosed()` method that you can use for `MatDialog` if you are using angular material. i am sure there are similiar mechanics in other UI libraries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Observable BehaviorSubject

**create-club.component.ts:**

```
private clubList = new BehaviorSubject(null);
public clubList$ = this.clubList.asObservable();

createClub() {
    this._clubService.createClub(this.clubDetails).subscribe((data: {}) => {
       this.clubList.next(data);
    });
    alert('Club Created');
}
```

club-list-component:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.clubList$.subscribe(updatedList=>{
    console.log(updatedList);
  });
}
```